# Visual Studio Code cannot import assemblies containing Hyper-V data types to build PowerShell objects

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, assemblies

### Problem Description and Background

I am building some custom PowerShell objects that require the Hyper-V data types.  I found the Hyper-V data types by using commands

1. `[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().FullName | ? {$_ -like "*hyper*" -or $_ -like "*virt*"}`
2. `Get-TypeData -TypeName Microsoft.HyperV.*`

The current best practice about importing assemblies into powershell scripts is that seems to recommend [Add-Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-7.1) instead of [using assembly](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6653#issuecomment-858767184).  T*here is more discussion about using assembly on the boards but I have been able to reproduce the error with both methods*

I then created a custom type BMachine in PowerShell Visual Studio Code

```
using assembly 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Common.Types\v4.0_10.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Common.Types.dll'
using assembly 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Objects\v4.0_10.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Objects.dll'

class BMachine {
    [String] $Name 
    [IPAddress] $Address
    [Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VirtualMachine] $Machine

    BMachine ([String] $name) {
        $this.Name = $name
        $drivePath = "Machines\" + $name + "\" + $name + ".vhdx"

        $this.Machine = New-VM -Generation 2 -Name $name -MemoryStartupBytes 1GB -NewVHDPath $drivePath -NewVHDSizeBytes 40GB -Path ("C\Machines\" + $name + "\")
    }
    
}

$machine = [BMachine]::new( $(Get-Content \users\griot\Dropbox\scripts\single_words.txt | Get-Random) )
$machine
```

When I run the code in Visual Studio I always get the error `Unable to find type [Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VirtualMachine]`  You can see it in the screenshot

[image]

### How Did I Narrow it Down to a Visual Studio Code Issue

1. I get the same error when using Add-Type, Using Assembly, or even trying Import Hyper-V
2. Uninstalling VS Code and blowing away all my configs before a restart did not fix the issue
3. Reinstalling the PowerShell extensions did not fix it
4. I still got the parse error when I installed the PowerShell Pro Tools extension (licensed)
5. However running script in Windows Terminal runs with no problem

**Output From PowerShell 7 Terminal**

2021-08-03 14:36 BMachine> .\BMachine.ps1

Name     Address Machine

---

shopmate         VirtualMachine (Name = 'shopmate') [Id = 'f26280fd-80c4-4e7b-a713-de4b4b31885d']

2021-08-03 14:36 BMachine>

### My Question

What can I do so VS Code detects and imports builtin Microsoft data types and avoid getting the parse errors I am seeing?

Comment: Could you explain why you're accessing the raw DLLs rather than importing the Hyper-V module? I think you could avoid this issue by using the module but there may be a reason you haven't explored that.

Comment: I did try putting Import-Module Hyper-V as the first line of the script without using and assemblies but that did not work.  That was the first thing I did.  Sorry for not explaining that

Comment: Oh I did mention trying that in the description but did not specify the exact command

Comment: When you say the Import-Module way didn't work, can you expand on that? Was it the same issue or was there another error?

Comment: @Persistent13 If I only use `Import-Module -Name "Hyper-V"` the `Unable to find type` error still occurs.  I also tried using the assemblies and the module imports and still get the error.

Comment: Sadly I'm uncertain as to what is happening here, it seems like something environment related. I can get the class you've created to work without issue in VS Code using both the Import-Module way and the using assembly way.

Comment: @Persistent13 I am in the exact same boat as you :-).  After researching this since have come to the two conclusions 1) The problem is due to Visual Studio Code not being able to invoke the correct namespace at runtime. 2) Even though PowerShell sees the data types and in the Hyper-V module there are some problems loading the data types since C# support for Hyper-V programming is in from the \root\v2 namespace in Hyper-V WMI namespace.  This namespace has been deprecated since 2012.  See [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hyperv_v2/using-the-virtualization-wmi-provider).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with Visual Studio.  The assemblies needed to create custom HyperV objects are not in HyperV or virtualization assemblies.  All the PowerShell Hyper-V cmdlets are just wrapppers for commands and classes in Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure Namespace.  Most PowerShell commands having to do with physical machines, networking or hardware do not have access to those objects.  You have to use the CIM classes and instances.